# SQL Analyse if Farmer has Animal

Tags: sql

I want to make from a table like this:

```
Person      Animal  
Farmer 1    Horse  
Farmer 2    Horse  
Farmer 4    Horse  
Farmer 1    Sheep  
Farmer 3    Sheep  
Farmer 4    Sheep  
Farmer 2    Cow  
Farmer 3    Cow  
....
```

A table like this

```
........................Horse  Sheep  Cow  
Farmer 1............1..........1........0  
Farmer 2............1..........0........1  
Farmer 3............0..........1........1
```

So if a Farmer has an animal the table should contain a 1, otherwise a 0. 
Of course it should work for much more farmers and animals.

I would so much appreciate if someone could help me, as i am totally new to SQL... I guess it should work with PIVOT and EXISTS but i am too stupid to write a correct query.

Edit:

Is it possible to add a second header? Like if I have a third column with "location" in my original table, with "house" for the sheeps, "garden" for the horses etc... I now want to have in the final table the corresponding location above the animal row. So first column is farmers, first row is location, second row is animal and then there are 0th and 1th depending if the farmer has this animal or not. So basically I want to insert a row after having the final table.

Comment: yes, it'd be a pivot query, but we won't write it for you. you write it, we (maybe) try help fix it.

Comment: Can you show us what's your approach

Comment: _"i am too stupid to write a correct query"_ - Well, if that is the case, you can avoid using `PIVOT` and simply look at using conditional aggregation. There are plenty of answers already on this site, so a simple search should suffice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
    Person
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN Animal = 'Horse' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Horse
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN Animal = 'Sheep' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Sheep
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN Animal = 'Cow' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Cow
FROM
    Table
GROUP BY
    Person
```

Whether you use Pivot or conditional aggregation you will need to know the values in the animal column unless you want to use dynamic sql which means you dynamically build a statement similar to this.

Comment: thank you very much. If i want to run this dynamically in C# i would make a for loop and read the n-th value of the column to the query. Somehow like ,SUM(CASE WHEN Animal = '" + _Animal.Rows[n] + "' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS " + _Animal.Rows[n], where i would have to query Distinct Animal column to an _Animal List. Probably there are much nicer ways to do this (if my way works at all)

Comment: No, i should use the StringBuilder i guess. I found it here in stackoverflow and i guess this will be a good solution.

Comment: if you want to do it dynamically you can do it in c#  or sql, and yes you would build the string based on a DISTINCT ANIMAL COUNT.  Watch out for SQL injection if that Animal value can come from a webform or user input in free text.  The thing to keep in mind is that pivot tables are only useful to a certain number of columns so you probably don't want 100 types of animals....

Comment: ok, i simplified it with the farmer and animal. Normally it is much more data and the number of "animals" can be more than 100. Thanks really a lot, i will test it as soon as i have my computer with C#

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would do it:

```
SELECT X.Person,
       CASE WHEN COUNT(Horse.Person) >= 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as Horse,
       CASE WHEN COUNT(Sheep.Person) >= 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as Sheep,
       CASE WHEN COUNT(Cow.Person) >= 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as Cow
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Person FROM table_I_want_to_make) X
LEFT JOIN table_I_want_to_make Horse ON X.Person = Horse.Person AND Horse.Animal = 'Horse'
LEFT JOIN table_I_want_to_make Sheep ON X.Person = Sheep.Person AND Sheep.Animal = 'Sheep'
LEFT JOIN table_I_want_to_make Cow ON X.Person = Cow.Person AND Cow.Animal = 'Cow'
GROUP BY X.Person
```

And before you say... oooh I can't do any number of columns.  Don't.  You need to know all the column names to do a pivot also.

To make it "dynamic" the only way is with dynamic sql to generate the above or the pivot which both will compile to the same thing and I think the above is clearer.

To make dynamic sql we need to know what platform you are using because it is not standard.

Comment: Why are you doing any `JOIN`s for this? I don't see why that is necessary.

Comment: @Nicarus - You are right a simple group by would work for this single table he "wants to make", but I was doing the "general case" which I see much more often where the data is in another table.